# How to ask about a person's academic qualification?

Tags: translation, sentence-request

The literal translation of the sentence I use in my mother tongue to ask about academic qualification is "How far did you study?"

Does this sentence sound normal to English ear?
If not, please suggest a suitable sentence (For casual conversation ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written is easily understood but it's not exactly how a native would say it.

Instead you could say

> How far did you get in your studies?